# Insert ID in React Modal

Tags: javascript, html, react-modal

I am using https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/modal/ this modal. I would like to add an `id` attribute in div which have `modal` class. How can I do that ?

[image]

Comment: In react, you usually prefer `refs` in identifying an element/component rather than via ID. Why do you need to insert an ID?

Comment: I would like to attach an event that's why I need an ID. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try simply adding an `id` prop?:

```
<Modal
  trigger={<Button onClick={this.handleOpen}>Show Modal</Button>}
  open={this.state.modalOpen}
  onClose={this.handleClose}
  basic
  size='small'
  id="theIdHere"
>
...
```

it worked for me

```
<div class="ui page modals dimmer transition visible active" style="display: flex !important;">
  <div id="theIdHere" class="ui small basic modal transition visible active">
  ...
```

However, the `modal` div is only available once the modal is shown, so be careful to attach the event upon modal `open` and remove once the modal is closed